# SSH: Don't prompt for password in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsa-key-fingerprint

I'm using ssh and have a passwordless ssh setup for my system. Using ssh in a script works fine, but if the user specifies a host that don't has a passwordless ssh setup the script prompts for a password and hangs.

How could I avoid the password prompt and return an error if passwordless ssh is not setup for the host?

Comment: As there are more reasons for ssh to prompt http://serverfault.com/a/61936 seems to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@hostname
```

See man page of `ssh_config` for more details.

Comment: This doesn't work for private key authentication, where ssh asks for the passphrase for the key.

Answer (score 8):

Setting *PasswordAuthentication* didn't work for me but this did:

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes user@hostname
```

From ssh_config(5)

> **BatchMode** If set to ''yes'', passphrase/password querying will be disabled. This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where
>   no user is present to supply the password. The argument must be
>   ''yes'' or ''no''. The default is ''no''.

For good measure you could also throw in *StrictHostKeyChecking* so it will automatically accept keys and avoid the prompt.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes user@hostname
```